# Problem with updating kivy.uix.progressbar.ProgressBar

Tags: python, kivy, progress-bar, python-3.10

I am trying to write a simple app that will generate a pdf report with some plots. I also want to add a `progressbar window` where you can see the progress of the program. Well, I did it, but I have a problem with the widget. Namely, when performing tasks, the progressbar `value` increases, but the widget you see **doesn't**.

Why is that? I don't know. That's why I'm asking you for help.

**My code**

*Libraries*

```
import os
import re
import time
from fpdf import FPDF
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# set window size
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '450')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '300')

import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.progressbar import ProgressBar
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserListView
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
```

**Body of the GeneratePDF class**

```
class FileChooserPopup(Popup):
    pass        

class GeneratePDF():
    def __init__(self, app_instance, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.app_instance = app_instance


    # --- other methods ---

    def create_progress_popup(self):
        # show progress popup
        content = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.progress_bar = ProgressBar(max=100, value=0, size_hint_x=0.8,
                                        pos_hint={'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5})
        self.percent_label = Label(text='0%', size_hint=(None, None),
                                size = (40,30),
                                pos_hint ={'center_x': 0.5,'center_y': 0.5})
        content.add_widget(self.progress_bar)
        content.add_widget(self.percent_label)
        self.progress = Popup(title='', content=content, size_hint=(0.8,0.8),
                              separator_height=0)
       
        # dismiss the file chooser popup
        self.app_instance.file_chooser.dismiss()

        self.progress.open()

    def update_progress(self, value):
        current = self.progress_bar.value
        current += value
        self.progress_bar.value = current
        self.percent_label.text = f'{int(current)}%'

    # --- other methods ---

    def generate_raport1(self, instance, selection, *args):
        # opening file
        if selection:
            self.selected_file = selection[0]

            # Create the progress popup
            self.create_progress_popup()

            # start generating raport inthread
            Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.generate_report2(), 0)
        else:
            # dismiss the file chooser popup
            self.app_instance.file_chooser.dismiss()

    def generate_report2(self):
       
        # drawing plots and updating progressbar
        self.plot1(self.selected_file)
        self.update_progress(20)

        self.plot2()
        self.update_progress(20)

        self.plot3()
        self.update_progress(20)

        self.plot4()
        self.update_progress(20)

        # generate pdf raport
        self.write_pdf()
        self.update_progress(20)
        time.sleep(1)

        # deleting unnecessary png files
        for plot in self.plots: os.remove(plot)
       
        # showing message
        self.show_message_box()
```

**Body of App**

```
class RaportApp(App):
   
    def build(self):
        self.layout = RelativeLayout()
        self.generate_pdf = GeneratePDF(app_instance=self)
        self.button = Button(text="Choose File", on_release=self.show_file_chooser,
                             size_hint=(None,None), size=(200,50),
                             pos_hint={'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5})
        self.layout.add_widget(self.button)
        return self.layout
   
    def show_file_chooser(self, *args):
        username = os.getenv("USERNAME")
        content = FileChooserListView(path = f'C:\\Users\\{username}\\Desktop', filters=['*.csv'])
        self.file_chooser = FileChooserPopup(title="Choose a *.csv file", content=content, size_hint=(0.8, 0.8))
        content.bind(on_submit=self.generate_pdf.generate_raport1)
        self.file_chooser.open()

    def update_progress(self, value):
        self.generate_pdf.update_progress(value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    RaportApp().run()
```

This is my last version of the App. I'm using `Python 3.10` and `kivy 2.2.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Clock.schedule_once()` does not execute the code in another thread. It actually runs it on the main thread. You can use `threading` to execute code on another thread, then add `@mainthread` decorator on the `update_progress()` method to force it to run on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Well I did it and it still doesn't work. Maybe my implementation is wrong. Could you check?

This is my code with your idea.

```
def generate_raport1(self, instance, selection, *args):
        # opening file
        if selection:
            self.selected_file = selection[0]

            # Create the progress popup
            self.create_progress_popup()

            # start generating raport inthread
            thread = threading.Thread(target = self.generate_report2())
            thread.start()
        else:
            # dismiss the file chooser popup
            self.app_instance.file_chooser.dismiss()

    def generate_report2(self):
        
        # drawing plots and updating progressbar
        self.plot1(self.selected_file)
        main_thread()
        self.update_progress(20)

        self.plot2()
        self.update_progress(20)

        self.plot3()
        self.update_progress(20)

        self.plot4()
        self.update_progress(20)

        # generate pdf raport
        self.write_pdf()
        self.update_progress(20)

        print(self.progress_bar.value)

        # deleting unnecessary png files
        for plot in self.plots: os.remove(plot) 
        
        # showing message
        self.show_message_box()
```